# Checking the values in a list against Pandas DataFrame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, sentiment-analysis

I have a Pandas DataFrame with a list of words and their associated emotions (each can have several emotions attached to it). Something like this:

[image]

I have also extracted the tokens of a text, using Spacy, into a list. something like ['study', 'Maths', 'easy', 'great', 'study',...]

In order to match the tokens in the tokenList to the associated emotions in the emotion dataframe (df_lexicon) I have tried the following:
`

```
emotions = []

// adding the token to emotions list if it exists in the emotion dataframe

for i in tokensList:
  if i in df_lexicon['word'].values:
    emotions.append(i)

// printing the row including the word and emotion

for i in emotions:
  print(df_lexicon[df_lexicon['word']==i])
```

`But that gives me:`

```
       word   emotion
10215  ban  negative
       word   emotion
10220  mad    negative
       mad    fear
.
//(and many more)
```

I don't know how to add the results to a new DataFrame instead of just printing them. Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `.isin()` to check the dataframe against the values in the list:

```
s = df_lexicon['word'].isin(tokenList)

new_df = df_lexicon[s]
```

Please let me know if it solved your problem.

Comment: Thank you Ali. But it just gives me an empty dataframe. so, new_df has two columns (word and emotion) but they are empty although they should not be.

Comment: I edited my answer. It should work now.

Comment: Awesome. damet garm! worked. appreciate it.

Comment: Glad it helped. Fada!